# Incorrect tooltip for suspended users

Tags: support, account-suspension, tooltips

While trying to accept an answer during suspension gives a tool tip

> suspended users can't vote

shouldn't that be

> suspended users can't accept answers

Comment: I'd argue that accepting an answer is analogous to a vote.  Perhaps you're right in saying that it should be worded a little better, though.

Comment: [Accepting is a vote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/278573)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost everything you can do to a post beyond writing or editing it is *technically* a vote. Well, less today than it was previously after we overhauled flags quite a bit, but that text is reminiscent of the time that it was. When you flagged something, you basically voted to say a post was [whatever flag said], just like you'd vote to close, reopen or delete. This actually makes a *lot* of sense when a consensus is meaningful when it comes to the system doing stuff based on a consensus.

I'd be *for* changing it to:

> Suspended users can't vote on or accept answers

But even though we hand out way more than we've ever handed out in the past on Stack Overflow, suspensions are still very much an exceptional situation. The guidance sufficiently conveys "You can't do this because you're suspended".

We're going to be a little more .. selective when it comes to minor copy changes because of the internationalization effort. Every time we add or change a string in English, we task volunteer translators on several sites to review and possibly re-translate it.

I'm not saying no, and I'm tossing this into a sheet I'm keeping of minor copy changes that I'm considering for when we send the next batch of strings to trickle back down to the international sites - as suspensions are confusing enough in English. But, it'll be .. a while.

Answer (score 5):

Accepting an answer is a special *vote* you have on a question you asked. Technically makes that the tooltip correct.

However, it seems a small change to make and indeed, an updated wording makes it actually clear what you did. I wouldn't bother too much though.

Answer (score 2):

Accept practically counted as vote - you can use this vote on an answer that you consider to be correct for you - so I believe the wording is good and I wouldn't change it.